# How to add best sellers block in home page in magento 2.0?

Tags: magento-2.2.1

How to add best sellers block in home page using magento 2.0???Anyone Know it Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

You can use below extension to add bestsellers products.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-product-slider-extension/best-sellers.html

Once you install and configure, you can write below in CMS home page content. It will render bestselling products in home page.

```
{{block class="Mageplaza\Productslider\Block\BestSellerProducts" template="Mageplaza_Productslider::productslider.phtml" products_count="8" heading="Best Sellers" description="Here is your Best Sellers description"}}
```